# KineticJS: .SetFill on a polygon updates the fill property but doesn't fill it with color

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have an existing codebase which creates a Stage, and then adds some layers and in one of the layers KineticJS Polygons are drawn. Now I need to update the background of the polygons when user clicks an element that is outside of the stage.

I have managed to get the stage details and then the exact polygon that I wanted to change and also managed to change the `fill` the polygon with `.SetFill` method. When I access the polygon's properties, I see the fill property is set correctly. But the background of polygon is not changed.

Is there anything that we need to do after the `.SetFill` function? Or, what is the proper way to change/update the fill of a KineticJS shape after its creation? I don't see any update or redraw methods...

The code is in Clojurescript, so I don't have exact JS code, but these are the steps that I have:

1. `polygon.setFill(color hexcode)`
2. `layer.add(polygon)`
3. `stage.add(layer)`
4. `stage.draw()`

Comment: try firing `layer.draw()` function after changing the background, plus go through the following resource, it might be due to the cache issue KineticJS has. Ref: https://github.com/lavrton/kineticjs-tips-and-tools

Comment: May I know why the question is downvoted? Is it missing anything

Comment: Only the person who down-voted would be able to answer that :D, anyhow, is it possible for you to create a snippet of your code on jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't because it's in Clojurescript. I would really love if there was something similar to JSFiddle in Clojurescript !

Comment: And i tried firing layer.draw() , but it didn't work though. I am trying other options now. Thanks BTW

Comment: In your click handler, first set the color and then draw the layer. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a kinetic.js example of updating the background of a polygon using the `setAttrs` method. After the change, the `batchDraw` method is used to update the layer.

```js
let index = 0;
const colors = [
  [0, 'yellow', 1, 'red'],
  [0, 'red', 1, 'yellow']
];
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (index++ > 0) index = 0;
  polygon.setAttrs({
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: colors[index]
  });
  // force update of layer
  layer.batchDraw();
});

const stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 615,
  height: 145
});
const layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
const polygon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  sides: 5,
  radius: 70,
  fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {
    x: -50,
    y: -50
  },
  fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {
    x: 50,
    y: 50
  },
  fillLinearGradientColorStops: colors[index],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  draggable: true
});
layer.add(polygon);
stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
<div>Click or drag polygon</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. The batchDraw method also didn't update. I eventually did a workaround: Delete all the children and redraw everything with the color filled. It's ugly but it works.